# My webserver service is not stopping

Tags: java, android, webserver, android-service

I have created a android app that creates a webserver and listens on port 1234 the problem is this that when i hit start server button then it works fine and when i hit stop button it gives me a error in logcat and start itself again..This is my service any help will appreciated.

Here goes the Code...

```
package dolphin.developers.com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class hot1 extends Service {


    private static final String TAG = null;
    JHTTP pro;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Server Started.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");


            try{
                File documentRootDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/");
                  pro = new JHTTP(documentRootDirectory, 1234);



            }
            catch(IOException e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }



      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override

        public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        pro.stop();


      }


      @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart");


            pro.start();


            }

}
```

Logcat:

```
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service dolphin.developers.com.hot1@45fe6990 with Intent { cmp=dolphin.devlopers.com/dolphin.developers.com.hot1 }: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at dolphin.developers.com.hot1.onStart(hot1.java:72)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
08-05 12:51:54.210: E/AndroidRuntime(511):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: That thing on line 72? It's `null`

Comment: 72 line is whole space..

Comment: @Prakhar : probably `pro` is `null`

Comment: You should check on start, whether pro is null or not. If null you instantiate again `pro = new JHTTP(documentRootDirectory, 1234);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to avoid calling the function when it is null

```
if(pro != null){
   pro.stop();
}
```

How do you start the JHHTP Client?

```
JHHTP pro = new JHTTP(rootDir, 1234) //second one is Port
```

because the constructor looks like this:

```
public JHTTP(File documentRootDirectory, int port) 
       throws IOException { //blah blah blah }
```